# Why is the loop not stopping and why is the user input not showing up?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I have a piece of code for which I am struggling to understand its behaviour.

```js
var play = prompt('Do you want to play?');
var userInput = "";
if (play == 'yes')
do {
    var word = prompt('Enter a word.');
    var play2 = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
    " " + word++;
}
while (play == 'yes');
console.log(userInput);
```

1. I don't understand why the loop does not end. Shouldn't it stop prompting the questions if `yes` is not entered according to the while loop?
2. I don't understand why the user input is not written to `console.log`. I'm trying to get all user input concatenated.

Comment: The loop doesn't stop because play will always be 'yes', you never redefine what `play` is

Comment: `" " + word++;` <-- what do you think that is doing?

Comment: for 2.: you log the content of variable `userInput`. This is just a variable you assigned an empty string to. You never did anything else with it. So at the end when you call `console.log(userInput);` you basically log an empty string which will not be visible. you may want to add `userInput += word;`

Answer (score 0):

OP you use "var play" to create a variable, but after that you can just change it (play="whatever") or add to it by doing (play+="whatever").

In the loop for example "var play2" creates a new variable called play2, but then does nothing since you never read or write to it again.

You're never actually changing the value of play, so play always = yes once the loop is entered.

Same with the user input, you create the variable but then never write to it. You should be adding the words and a space to it on ever loop.

You're likely looking for something more like this:

```js
var play = prompt('Do you want to play?');
var userInput = "";
if (play == 'yes')
do {
    var word = prompt('Enter a word.');
    play = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
    userInput += word + " ";
}
while (play == 'yes');
console.log(userInput);
```

(edited to reflect comment suggestions)

Comment: I think it would be helpful to point out what you changed, what OP did wrong in the first place and why this didn't do what he thought it would